# Downloading a PDF from a HTML string out of a View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get download a PDF parsed from a form's HTML code using NReco.PdfConverter. After finding out AJAX isn't going to work I went with form actions per suggestion in numerous posts. However, this raises new issues I can't figure out on my own:

1. How can I use a model to replace the ugly `[ValidateResponse(false)]` in my controller?
2. <strike>How can I make sure the file actually gets opened?</strike>
3. <strike>Formatting the HTML string in the right way so that PdfGenerator can work with it.</strike>
4. Adding CSS to the PDF

EDIT:
Ok I updated the Controller code, I can now succesfully create a PDF file. I added the following lines of code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
```

However the contents are not what I expect. I suspect the JSON.stringify isn't correctly formatting the string. Turns out i was using the wrong jQuery selector and actually selected the form that contained the print button. That being fixed I can now succesfully load the HTML string into the PDF, except it's missing the CSS. How can I make sure that the PDF looks exactly like the webpage using te PdfConverter?

Html:

```
<form action="User/Template/Print" method="POST" id="print-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" hidden ng-model="strHtml" name="strHtml" ng-init="printToPdf()" />
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">@Html.Raw(new Icon("print").Html) Print</button>
</form>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module("app").controller("FormController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.printToPdf = function () {
        var strHtml = $('#werkorderFormulier form').html();
        $scope.strHtml = JSON.stringify(strHtml);
    }
});
```

Print action in TemplateController:

```
public FileResult Print(FormCollection fC)
{
    var pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
    var strHtml = fC.GetValue("strHtml").AttemptedValue;
    var pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GeneratePdf(strHtml);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're using to create the PDF, but I know that *all* C# PDF libraries have limited CSS support. Libraries that support HTML and CSS to PDF have to actually translate that HTML and CSS into commands understood by the PDF format. Some libraries do a better job than others, but none have achieved one-to-one parity. Generally, about the best you can expect is [CSS Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/) support. Which is actually fairly limited. It's amazing how much CSS Level 3 has brought us and how little we used to be able to control.

If your goal here is to get something like a screenshot of the webpage as a PDF, then your only real option is a library called [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). It's a compiled binary, rather than a true library you can add to your code. You'll have to call out to the filesystem and execute it, which is not ideal, depending on the trust environment you may find yourself in. Still, wkhtmltopdf is unique in that it integrates the WebKit engine, used in Safari and formerly Chrome and Opera. In other words, it literally renders the webpage, just as a browser would, and then essentially converts the bitmap into a PDF. In that way you can get near perfect parity of look and feel.

Comment: I'm using [NReco.PdfGenerator](http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx) to generate the pdf